# Is there tool that resolves property values?

Tags: c++, msbuild

For large C++ projects that have lots of different *.vcxproj files and are constantly inheriting/overwriting properties at different levels of the project, it can get confusing as to what a certain property resolves to.

Is there a tool that can help with this?

Comment: Visual Studio does this.

Comment: Does it require solution files to do this?  The current project I'm working only has the *vcxproj files (created manually) so using Visual Studio doesn't quite work.

Comment: You can open project files directly in VS, it will create a temporary solution for it. Otherwise run the build with diagnostic verbosity and it will print a bunch of 'Property reassignment' lines.